# View progress to http.get() query (by vue-resource) from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vue-resource

```
this.$http.get('cities_&_stops/' + this.search_city_name[0].toUpperCase() + '.json' )
    .then(response => {
      this.cities_array = [];
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(cities => {
      //console.log("cities from db -> "+cities);
      for(let city in cities){
        this.city_object = {
          name :  cities[city].toUpperCase(),
          class : ''
        }
        //console.log("pushing in array -> " + this.city_object.name);
        this.cities_array.push(this.city_object);
        //console.log("in city array -> " + this.city_object.name);
      }
      //console.log("what is in city array? -> " + this.cities_array);
      this.search_feature();
    })
```

This is my query by http.get() method (using vue-resouce) from firebase database.

How can I see my progress in console(in %).

Comment: Is that URL legal?  & should be escaped, right?

Comment: Its legal. It is linked to -> `Vue.http.options.root='https://something.com/'` in main.js by vue-resource. Need Progress status in % of above http request.Will Show it on ProgressBar.